# Chained audio setup works on everything but Mac

Tags: macos, audio, usb, displayport, apple-silicon

I have a setup where I have a dock that plugs a single USB-C connection into a computer. The dock has a DisplayPort cable to a monitor with a 3.5mm audio jack which some headphones are plugged into.

I use this monitor for my Windows machine, a Linux machine and a Mac M1 laptop.
On the Windows and Linux machines, it works perfectly.
On the Mac the audio constantly fades in and out from the headphones.  When it leaves the headphones, it actually plays audio through the monitor speakers, and then fades back to the headphone.  The "fading" happens a couple times a second.

Does anyone know why this is happening and how to fix it?

OS Version: Monterey 12.6.1